# I received a series of downvotes

Tags: discussion, downvotes, voting, serial-voting

Recently I noticed that I had received a number of downvotes on about 10 answers in a span of 1 minute. That's about 6 seconds per question.

[image]

Now I don't mind criticism at all but how is it humanly possibly to open a question, read the post, then read the answer, then evaluate the quality of the answer and finally downvote it just in under 6 seconds unless it was just a co-incidence that 10 people were viewing my posts and all happened to cast a vote at the same minute.

To me, it seems like some deliberate act or some sort of revenge act but I am not sure.

How can one tackle a situation a like this?

Comment: [What can I do if I'm the victim of serial downvoting?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/what-can-i-do-if-im-the-victim-of-serial-downvoting)

Comment: DAMN YOU, META SPLIT!!!

Comment: @gnat always to the rescue with a duplicate/related link. Thanks!

Comment: Just got a notification that the serial voting was reversed ! Thanks everyone for your feedbacks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Servy points out [the original reference for this over on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/what-can-i-do-if-im-the-victim-of-serial-downvoting), but you've experienced serial downvoting.

For a rapid string of downvotes like that, we generally recommend waiting a day or two to allow the vote fraud detection mechanisms a chance to examine and invalidate these votes. If it happens to miss these after that point, flag one of your posts and describe what happened. At that point, moderators can contact SE staff to manually invalidate the downvotes if appropriate.

It was pretty clear who was behind this, so I provided them a gentle warning not to do this again. Hopefully they'll listen to that advice.

Comment: Thanks @BradLarson ! I just got the notification that serial voting was reversed.

Comment: @BradLarson What should I do if the systemm didn't reverse the revenger downvotes?

Comment: @Mederic - What you did (following on with a flag) is the right action. At first, we couldn't see who did this because they hid their tracks well, but the last few votes were enough for us to determine the culprit. SE employees have to manually invalidate these, so I've queued this for them to act on. It may take up to a week for that request to be processed, given the number of sites they have to oversee. The votes will be invalidated eventually, though.

Comment: @BradLarson Thanks for getting back to me I did flag the 6 downvotes that seemed serial in the last 4 days I don't know if it was the same person but I thought maybe since they had happened at the same timeframes I'll wait patiently then.

Answer (score 2):

That looks like Serial downvoting.  It means that someone didn't like something you wrote, and is methodically going through posts and downvoting them all.

Serial voting as blatant as that will probably get undone automatically by the system in less than a week.  normally a day or 2

Comment: Probably is the key. Been downvote around 10 days after closing a question where the downvoter answered, only half ot the downvotes have been reversed.